# Data structure for when key and value are equally "important"

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, performance, mapping

So, this is probably a stupid question, but I have a mapping of unique IDs to unique values. Sometimes I want the value for a certain ID, sometimes I want to know the ID of a certain value. I search more than I modify the collection. I'm wondering if there's a special datastructure that makes sense here, or if I should just maintain two copies of the collection (which is never super large)--one keyed by ID, and one keyed by value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining two copies of the collection is the canonical solution.

Note that the two directions can use different collection types if appropriate (e.g. hash tables with different hash functions, a hash table and a balanced tree, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Something like Google's [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Comment: Came here to post this. `BiMap<Integer, String> map = new HashBiMap<Integer,String>(); map.put(1,"Hello"); Integer id = map.inverse().get("Hello");`. But pretty much the implementation is actually 2 HashMaps maintained on each put().